# Full Backup of non-rooted device in 2017

Tags: backup, android-sdk, samsung-galaxy-s7

My Galaxy S7 has developed a problem with it battery (where it is continually turning off / rebooting) and so I need to get it repaired/replaced by my insurer.

The only issue is that, for data protection, they wipe every device before repairing.

Although I have back ups of most of my apps, all my photos, contacts & sms messages I have a lot of settings, multiple non-web based email accounts etc. set up on the phone so having to start from stratch would be a real hassle.

I therefore want to back up the entire phone, like a drive image, onto my Macbook so that I can simply copy the backup onto my new/repaired device once the battery issue is sorted.

I thought I had found a solution in this thread: [Full Backup of non-rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/full-backup-of-non-rooted-devices)

However that is nearly 5 years old and so the instructions do not match the current version of Android SDK, seemingly now called Android Studio (the previous instructions ask you to locate a folder called 'platform-tools' but this isn't created by the current version of the SDK).

Anyone know of any updated instructions on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: *Android Studio* has nothing to do with it (that's a development environment). The instructions for `adb backup` remain the same (for the basic requirements, follow our [adb tag-wiki](/tags/adb/info) to "minimal installation of ADB"). I'm not aware of any news in that sector, speaking of "full backup of non-rooted devices".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really crucial changed since then. Android SDK is now installed together with Android Studio, however can be installed [separately](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html). Platform tools, which contain ADB, are now delivered separately from SDK. Here is the link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html

After the installation you will find adb binary in `platform-tools` directory. All other points from those answer are still true.

Consider also [TWRP backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/173646/94888) possibility, which though, requires TWRP.

Comment: Where can I find the 'platform-tools' folder though? That was why I was thinking that the change to Android Studio had made the instructions invalid.

Doing a Finder search for any files or folders with 'platform' or 'tools' in the name doesn't bring this up on my Macbook...

Comment: Yep, platform tools now go separately. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Samsung [Smart Switch](http://www.samsung.com/uk/smart-switch/)? You can easily make a backup of your entire phone: Contacts, emails, messages... including your apps, settings and so and save them to your computer and easily restore them when needed

You can find a list of some softwares that can help you backup​ your phone's​ content [here](https://tunesgo.wondershare.com/samsung/samsung-backup-software.html)